# Where to find the output from traceResolution

Tags: typescript

If I switch traceResolution on in tsconfig.json, where will I find the output?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "traceResolution": true,
    ...
```

> --traceResolution => "Report module resolution log messages." From the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be reported via stdout (ie: your console/terminal), or wherever your typescript compiler is set to output to.

It can be quite verbose, especially on a large project, so you can't miss it!